# Replace a Date with last business day

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace a date with last business day of that month and getting message

> 'TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'str'

Code:

```
df['curr_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['curr_date'])
df['curr_date'] = df['curr_date'].replace('curr_date',df.loc[df.curr_date.isin(df.curr_date + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1))],inplace = True)
```

curr_date: 2020-01-31, 2020-02-29, 2020-03-31
I want the 2020-02-29 to be replaced with 2020-02-28 which is last business day in february. Thanks

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe with expected output.

Comment: curr_date: 2020-01-31, 2020-02-29, 2020-03-31, last business day for February was 02/28/2020 so 2020-01-31 & 2020-03-31 would not change but 2020-02-29 would be replaced with 2020-02-28

Comment: Please put this in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from defining an offset to business month end:

```
offs = pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(0)
```

Then define a function to compute the last business day for the current date:

```
def dateCorr(dat : pd.Timestamp) -> pd.Timestamp:
    dFwd = offs.rollforward(dat)
    return dFwd if dFwd.month == dat.month else offs.rollback(dat)
```

For the test purpose, save the "corrected" dates as a new column:

```
df['LastBDay'] = df.curr_date.apply(dateCorr)
```

so you will be able to compare source dates with new dates.

Of course in the final version of code replace *LastBDay* with
*curr_date*, to overwrite the existing column.

## Another, much faster solution

As you probably know, *Numpy* operates much quicker than *Pandas*, so
I looked for the way to do your task based solely on *Numpy*.

The result is that I found much faster solution:

```
df['LastBDay'] = np.busday_offset(
    df.curr_date.values.astype('M8[M]') + np.timedelta64(1, 'M'), -1, roll='forward')
```

Steps:

- `df.curr_date.values.astype('M8[M]')` - Convert *curr_date* to a date with
  **month** resolution.
- `+ np.timedelta64(1, 'M')` - Forward this date by one month.
- `np.busday_offset(` - Find the business day, starting from the first
  argument.
- `-1` - 1 day back.
- `roll='forward'` - This is a tricky detail. Since the offset is *-1*,
  the roll direction is **back**. But passing *back* here rolls the date
  sometimes **another** day back. So to avoid this another shift,
  this parameter must be just *forward*.

And now how faster is this solution.

Using *%timeit* I measured the execution time of the previous solution
for a sample of 16,000 rows, getting *2,47 s*.

But the execution time of this (second) solution is *12,8 ms* - **190 times
faster**.

This much better execution speed results also from the fact that the
second solution uses **vectorized** operations instead of application
of a function to each row.